What payment is valid to pay for a developer account?
I am trying to subscribe to the developer account. But every credit or debit card I try, fails authentication. I have tried 5 payment methods so far.
The order says that:

items in the order are not eligible for this payment type.

I persist anyway and the authentication fails.
So, what payment type is valid?
I have posted it on Apple discussions.apple.com, but there is no reply yet. I also note that another person had the same issues and there were no reply to his question either.
History:

My account used to be based in New Zealand. I moved to Australia some 6 months ago, but could not change the country to Australia, until a subscription had expired a few weeks ago.
I have added PayPal (with Australian debit cards) as a payment method.
I have added an Australian debit card as another payment method.
I wanted to get a company developer account, so I applied for it.
I got the DUN and went to pay.
The error was: “Details don't match.”
They do but I went in and re-entered all the company details again (at D&B).
It will now take at least 7 days to percolate through.
That's just getting too late for my deadline.
So I decided to create a personal developer Account
Now I get told that the: “Items in the order are not eligible for this payment.”
I can't get an Australian Credit card yet (as all my assets are liquid), but I have tried 2 different New Zealand credit cards and a Wise card, they all give the same error.

I suspect…
That the conversion from New Zealand to Australia has munted the account somehow.

Apple support is the best way to get this sorted. The old links to payments and changing region may help, but why keep guessing and just ask for pre-sales support from the online Apple Store in the region to which you want your account to be listed?

https://support.apple.com/en-au
Call 133-622

You can add some item to the normal retail cart online and also see if there’s a pre-sales chat or another dedicated phone to call.
Discussions.apple.com and this site are never appropriate places for customer support. Go direct to Apple for this as it’s likely not payment, but another issue with your account that we can’t see and they can.
